# SAML authentication for Opensearch Domain in VPC

Tags: proxy, saml, vpc, opensearch

I have deployed a AWS Opensearch cluster in a private subnet inside a VPC. Also, can access the same with a Proxy server in a public subnet with its public IP.
There are multiple docs for accessing Opensearch Dashboard with Proxy and AWS Cognito Service. But I want to setup SAML for public access. The documentation isn't clear enough for this use case.

Is there a way, we can setup SAML authentication for Opoensearch Domain with Proxy server with Azure as Identity Provider?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this with AWS's own SSO solution, which also supports SAML authentication. However, I came across this note in the documentation, which seems relevant.

> You can't change the SSO URL from its service-provided value, so SAML authentication for OpenSearch Dashboards does not support proxy servers.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/saml.html

Sadly it seems that, for now, you would either have to make the OpenSearch Domain public, use AWS Cognito, or stick with basic authentication for OpenSearch.